Comparison of Algebra vs A Survey of Modern Algebra by Birkhoff-Mac Lane
(I could not find anyone expert to discuss my question related to two books - since most of the experts around me followed Gallian/Fraleigh/Artin in their study of Algebra but not some classical books about which I was curious; so I am posting my question here.)
Two well-known mathematicians and authors Garrett Birkhoff and Saunders Mac Lane wrote two books:

Algebra

A Survey of Modern Algebra.


I wondered whether these books have too much difference? (I do not have copy of second one!) If the first one covers much basic topics in Algebra that an undergraduate/graduate student should know, why the authors motivated to write "Survey"? The word "Survey" suggest it is summary of some big theory. But compared to "Algebra" ($626$ pages), the book "A Survey of Modern Algebra"($512$ pages) looks not too small. So, what is difference in these two books? Do the authors covers something more in second book compared to first one, and vice-versa?
